# Ruby DataMapper, table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-datamapper

My tables repeat this line always

```
    property :created_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
property :updated_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
```

How do I DRY this out? Do I inherit, or have a module, or something else?

It's like this:

```
Class Foo
include DataMapper::Resource

property :id, Int
property :created_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
property :updated_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
end

Class Bar
include DataMapper::Resource

property :id, Int
property :created_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
property :updated_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now, :lazy => [:show]
end
```

these are repeated multiple times through each of the table

Comment: I little more information is needed. When/where this log shows? Is it inside the console? inside a model? Please try to explain it a bit better.

Comment: @GuilhermeBarrosAvila updated the post. I'm constantly repeating these fields. Not sure if module, class, or anything. If you don't mind me asking, I also have another question: How do you create a function that executes after the entire database has been created? For example, after creating the database and all its tables, I'd like to add some views . How do I get about doing this?

Comment: Made an answer for that. Mark as right if you feel like it, hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I understand what you are saying. Those are rails properties, which are created automatically. I'm not sure if there's a way of preventing this from happening, but those are definitely useful in many situations. I suggest you keep them, you will figure out their use as you learn more about Rails.

As for the views, you need to create a controller method and define a route to those methods inside `config/routes.rb`. I suggest you learn more about the MVC rails pattern. MVC is the core in which Rails is built upon.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ is a great website for learning rails. Try reading just a few articles and you'll be able to understand enough to build a full application in no time.

Comment: I do not have enough knowledge on Sinatra to answer you that. Despite of knowing how it works and how it should be done, I think it's best if you look for tutorials and books over the internet

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar. I used inheritance like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-constraints'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
DataMapper::Property::String.length(255)

class BaseTable
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :created_date, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now
  property :created_by, Integer
  property :updated_date, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now
  property :updated_by, Integer
end

class User < BaseTable
  property :userid, String
  property :email, String
  property :password, String
end

class Account < BaseTable
  property :name, String
  property :type, String
  property :location, String
  property :account_number, String
  property :total_balance, Integer
  property :cleared_balance, Integer
  property :marked_as_cleared_balance, Integer
  has n, :transactions, :constraint => :destroy
end

class Transaction < BaseTable
  property :id, Serial
  property :label, String
  property :cleared, Boolean
  property :date, Date
  property :description, String
  property :amount, Integer
  property :note, String
  property :balance, Integer
  belongs_to :account
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```